# How to create site using SharePoint Designer 2013 and SharePoint Server 2013?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

When i'm trying to create New 'Blank Site' in `SharePoint Designer 2013` it tells me

> This Web site must be created on a server that is running Microsoft SharePoint Foundation. Please choose another location.

I'm run `Microsoft SharePoint Server 2013`. Should i also install `Microsoft SharePoint Foundation 2013` or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're pointing your new `Blank Site` template at a location where SharePoint isn't installed. The best way to test if this is  the case would be to first try opening a site, put in the location of your new SharePoint installation and see if it resolves. If not then your problem lays in your SharePoint installation itself and you should review the documentation for that.